# Java InputMismatchException error when scanning from file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

Program is reading in from .txt file. The following error is thrown by the Scanner:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at project.pkg2.Project2.main(Project2.java:38)
Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This is the code doing all the reading in from the file. We have an integer which is the track count for the particular album. Then we have a track number, song title and artist on each line. The track number, title and artist are simply separated by commas.

Comment: Can you share the line that creates the Scanner?

Comment: sc.next() stops when it encounters a space " ". This is not what you want. You probably want to get all the line with sc.nextLine() and use String.split() to split the String into trackNumber (which you need to cast into int with exception handling), songName and artistName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `Scanner` has a `JavaWhiteSpace` delimiter, When you do `trackNumber = sc.nextInt();`, it gets "1, " and try to parse that to `int`, that will obviously fail.
Also, you forgot to collect endline character after getting `trackCount`.

Here's what you should do :

```
trackCount = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine(); // collect endline character
sc.useDelimiter(", ");
albumName = f.toString();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    trackNumber = sc.nextInt();
    songName = sc.next();
    artistName = sc.next();
    sc.nextLine(); // collect endline character

    processLine(albumName, artistName, songName, trackNumber);
}
sc.close();
```

Comment: thank you. however, I am now getting a null pointer exception pertaining to line 47 when I call a function. So I am not sure what is not getting initialized. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at project.pkg2.Project2.processLine(Project2.java:74)
 at project.pkg2.Project2.main(Project2.java:47)
Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @cheetodog That's an entirely unrelated error to this question! My answer solves your initial question, I've personally tested it and it worked! a NullPointerException generally means you're trying to read from a null reference. I'd suggest you look at `albumName` as the content of the file gets parsed correclty!